# Bonding on RedHat 6 with LACP

Tags: networking, redhat, lacp

I'm currently encountering an issue in RedHat 6.4. I have two physical NICs which I am trying to bond together using LACP.

I have the corresponding configuration set up on my switch, and I have implemented the recommended configuration from the RedHat Install Guide on my NICs.

However, when I start my network services, I'm seeing my LACP IP on the physical NICs as well as the bonding interface (respectively eth0, eth1 and bond0). i'm thinking I should only see my IP address on my bond0 interface?

The connectivity with my network is not established. I don't know what is wrong with my configuration.

Here are my ifcfg-eth0, eth1 and bond0 files (IP blanked for discretion purposes).

**ifcfg-eth0 :**

```
DEVICE=eth0

ONBOOT=yes

MASTER=bond0

SLAVE=yes

BOOTPROTO=none

USERCTL=no

TYPE=Ethernet

NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

**ifcfg-eth1 :**

```
DEVICE=eth1

ONBOOT=yes

MASTER=bond0

SLAVE=yes

BOOTPROTO=none

USERCTL=no

TYPE=Ethernet

NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

**ifcfg-bond0 :**

```
DEVICE=bond0

IPADDR=X.X.X.X

NETMASK=255.255.255.0

ONBOOT=yes

BOOTPROTO=none

USERCTL=no

NM_CONTROLLED=no

BONDING_OPTS="mode=4"
```

Thanks to anyone who can pinpoint my problem.

Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Network bonding : Modes of bonding

Modes 0, 1, and 2 are by far the most commonly used among them.

- Mode 0 (balance-rr)
  This mode transmits packets in a sequential order from the first available slave through the last. If two real interfaces are slaves in the bond and two packets arrive destined out of the bonded interface the first will be transmitted on the first slave and the second frame will be transmitted on the second slave. The third packet will be sent on the first and so on. This provides load balancing and fault tolerance.
- Mode 1 (active-backup)
  This mode places one of the interfaces into a backup state and will only make it active if the link is lost by the active interface. Only one slave in the bond is active at an instance of time. A different slave becomes active only when the active slave fails. This mode provides fault tolerance.
- Mode 2 (balance-xor)
  Transmits based on XOR formula. (Source MAC address is XOR’d with destination MAC address) modula slave count. This selects the same slave for each destination MAC address and provides load balancing and fault tolerance.
- Mode 3 (broadcast)
  This mode transmits everything on all slave interfaces. This mode is least used (only for specific purpose) and provides only fault tolerance.
- Mode 4 (802.3ad)
  This mode is known as Dynamic Link Aggregation mode. It creates aggregation groups that share the same speed and duplex settings. This mode requires a switch that supports IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link.
- Mode 5 (balance-tlb)
  This is called as Adaptive transmit load balancing. The outgoing traffic is distributed according to the current load and queue on each slave interface. Incoming traffic is received by the current slave.
- Mode 6 (balance-alb)
  This is Adaptive load balancing mode. This includes balance-tlb + receive load balancing (rlb) for IPV4 traffic. The receive load balancing is achieved by ARP negotiation. The bonding driver intercepts the ARP Replies sent by the server on their way out and overwrites the src hw address with the unique hw address of one of the slaves in the bond such that different clients use different hw addresses for the server.

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer my own question here in case anyone is having the same issue.

Turns out I just needed to deactivate the "*NetworkManager*" service on my RedHat Server. Turn it off, and deactivate it, then works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

~]#`service NetworkManager stop | chkconfig NetworkManager off`

Try This and if not continue with bellow command too

~]#`service network start/restart | chkconfig network on`